# Edit coupon placeholder woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

i want to change the placeholder coupon code i try it to add this function in functions.php

```
add_filter('woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'override_address_fields');
function override_address_fields( $address_fields ) {
$address_fields['coupon_code']['placeholder'] = 'Test';
return $address_fields;
}
```

But it's not worked

Here is the site if you need it, you need to put one product in cart to coupon code appear: https://banzairomania.ro/cos/

Answer (score 1):

I find out how to edit the placeholder, enter in cart.php find the placeholder and edit the parameter

```
placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'your place holder', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
```